# use Windows Authentication for private BitBucket git repo?

Tags: git, authentication, bitbucket, windows-authentication, bitbucket-server

Our development group uses Windows.  We are setting up a privately hosted BitBucket `git` repo.  Is there a way set up authentication with Windows Authentication?   Ideally, each developer would not have to do any configuration to get `push` access to the repo.  Rather an administrator would just configure something like "all members of the user group 'XYZ Developers' have push access to repo 'XYZ'".  Possible?

Comment: What does "privately hosted BitBucket" mean? A private repository on bitbucket.org? Or a privately-hosted [Bitbucket Server](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/server) (the thing that was previously called Stash)?

Comment: the Stash thing.  I'm hosting that on a Windows machine, so I'm thinking it may be able to leverage Windows permissions (which I must admit I am not an expert in)

Answer (score 3):

We're currently using Active Directory with Bitbucket Server (Stash).

See the section "Connecting Bitbucket Server" in the documentation [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/connecting-bitbucket-server-to-an-existing-ldap-directory-776640403.html) or [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/delegating-bitbucket-server-authentication-to-an-ldap-directory-776640402.html).

From the sounds of it you likely want to use the delegation option in the second link.